# C# wpf focus on cell datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, select, focus, cell

When I click on a cell in my *datagrid*, I get a black frame around it and blue highlighting behind the text. How can I do that with code?

With searching I was able to get this:

```
dataGrid.Focus();
dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.Items[2], dataGrid.Columns[3]);
```

This code will move the black frame to the 4th column and 3rd row but I don't know how to get highlighting working.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found an answer. I just can't believe it takes this much code to do something that seems to me such a simple thing. If anyone knows an easier way...please post. Thank you!

Website: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx

```
   public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null)
                        return childOfChild;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell GetCell(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridRow rowContainer, int column)
        {
            if (rowContainer != null)
            {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
                if (presenter == null)
                {
                    /* if the row has been virtualized away, call its ApplyTemplate() method
                     * to build its visual tree in order for the DataGridCellsPresenter
                     * and the DataGridCells to be created */
                    rowContainer.ApplyTemplate();
                    presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
                }
                if (presenter != null)
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell;
                    if (cell == null)
                    {
                        /* bring the column into view
                         * in case it has been virtualized away */
                        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dataGrid.Columns[column]);
                        cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column) as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell;
                    }
                    return cell;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        public static void SelectCellByIndex(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            if (!dataGrid.SelectionUnit.Equals(DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell))
                throw new ArgumentException("The SelectionUnit of the DataGrid must be set to Cell.");

            if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid row index.", rowIndex));

            if (columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex > (dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is an invalid column index.", columnIndex));

            dataGrid.SelectedCells.Clear();

            object item = dataGrid.Items[rowIndex]; //=Product X
            DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
            if (row == null)
            {
                dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
                row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
            }
            if (row != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, columnIndex);
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
                    dataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
                    cell.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
```